# iOS: How to group controls on screen, like in Settings?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My app needs a screen with several controls, such as a slider and a few switches. These controls will be used frequently, so I don't want to put them in a Settings bundle.

However, I like the way the controls are grouped in Settings and would like to do the same on this 'control' screen.

Obviously, Settings uses a table view controller in 'group' mode. Ideally, I'd like to lay out this view in Interface Builder, but I'll be darned if I can figure out how.

Do I need to set up this page programmatically, or is there a trick that will let me do this in IB?

TIA: John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do, is in my XIB file, I create my individual cells in design view, set up outlets for them, and then in the code of my data source, I will connect those cells to the table.

something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
        if(section == 0){
            if(row == 0){
                return basicCell;
            }
            if(row == 1){
                return linkedCell;
            }
            if (row == 2) {
                return tipsCell;
            }
        }
        if(section == 1){
            return wifiCell;
        }
        if(section == 2){
            return loginCell;
        }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: H'mmm. But how do you set up individual cells in IB? I've been trying everything I can think of, but it doesn't seem possible. I'm using Xcode 4, latest version.

Comment: In xcode, drag a uitableviewcell to the canvas (dont add to your view) just drop it by itself, then you can design it and set its properties, and link to an iboutlet